# CSS Aligning two DIVs side-by-side in the middle

Tags: html

[image]Dears Greeting,,

I want to Align two Divs side by side in the middle using HTML.

I really hope I can find the solution. I attached the code below
the final result should look like the attached image

many thanks & best regards

```css
.circle {
  width           : 300px;
  height          : 300px;
  line-height     : 300px;
  border-radius   : 50%;
  margin          : 50px;
  outline         : solid 1px black;
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  align-items     : center;
  font-size       : 30px;
  color           : #fff;
  text-align      : center;
  vertical-align  : middle;
  position        : relative;
  box-shadow      : inset -10px -10px 100px #000, 10px 10px 20px black
                  , inset 0px 0px 10px black;
  display         : inline-block;
  margin          : 5%;  
  background      : white
  }
```

```html
<div class="circle"><a href="https://www.w.com/">1</a></div>
<div class="circle"><a href="https://www.w.com/">2</a></div>
```

Comment: `flex` is a parent style property, not a child property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet which you have shared has two different `<div>` for each element and your `CSS` also does not have `.margin` or `.width` proportion to match the center of the page.

You can add parent wrapper `<div>` around your both circle `<div>` elements.

See if this snippet works for you:

```css
.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px;
  outline: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 100px #000, 10px 10px 20px black, inset 0px 0px 10px black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5%;
  background: white
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <div class="circle"><a href="https://www.w.com/">1</a></div>
  <div class="circle"><a href="https://www.w.com/">2</a></div>
</div>
```